# Axis 1.4 SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize

Tags: java

I want to call a soap web service using axis 1.4 to generate the source code:
the response format is String and the request format is an xml sent in string format:
the error encountered is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.socgen.interrogationfde.infogreffe.generated.WebServicesProduitsBindingStub.getProduitsWebServicesXML(WebServicesProduitsBindingStub.java:146)
    at com.socgen.interrogationfde.infogreffe.services.InfogreffeService.main(InfogreffeService.java:61)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:FR07166945L

org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2470)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.socgen.interrogationfde.infogreffe.generated.WebServicesProduitsBindingStub.getProduitsWebServicesXML(WebServicesProduitsBindingStub.java:146)
    at com.socgen.interrogationfde.infogreffe.services.InfogreffeService.main(InfogreffeService.java:61)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCE`enter code here`lement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    ... 4 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using and directly calling the URL of the soap web service with [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) from spring boot.

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate ();
    String fooResourceUrl`enter code here`
       = "http: // localhost: 8080 / spring-rest / foos";
    ResponseEntity <String> response
       = restTemplate.getForEntity (fooResourceUrl + "/ 1", String.class);
    assertThat (response.getStatusCode (), equalTo (HttpStatus.OK));
```